# Save integer to file and retrieve it

Tags: python

```
myFile = open('high scores.py', 'w')

if player1_total > player2_total :
        myFile.write(player1_total)
else :
        myFile.write(player2_total)
myFile.close
```

Comment: `myFile.close()`, with the brackets, to make the function call and flush the data to the file.

Comment: Thanks this was partly the problem and it is now working. Any idea on how to read the file every time I run the code so I can get the top 5 highest scores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myFile = open('high scores.py', 'w')

if player1_total > player2_total :
        myFile.write(str(player1_total))
else :
        myFile.write(str(player2_total))
myFile.close()
```

The issue is that you need to cast the integer to string before writing. easiest way is  `str(player2_total)`

Also close the file once done [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

> When you’re done with a file, call f.close() to close it and free up
>   any system resources taken up by the open file.

But a concise way to write it is give in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723293/1552998).

More info on using the context manager `with open():`  can be found in [PEP-0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) & read up on this [blog post](https://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/) as well

Comment: Are you intending to explain the change you made?

Comment: The issue is not that the OP did not _intend_ to close the file, but rather that they just referenced the function and did not call it. You also fixed the issue of not being able to write integers directly but haven't explained that.

Comment: @roganjosh i think `myFile.close` in the orginal question was to close it the file. The actual issue why his code didn't work was that the integer wasn't cast to string

Comment: `myFile.close` doesn't do anything. The function is never called. Removing from the code would have changed nothing; indeed, initially your only change was to _call_ the function by adding parentheses. My point is that referenced documentation on _why_ you need to call `close` does not address the fact that their _attempt_ to do so actually did nothing.

Comment: In any case, the question has an answer and now I feel like I'm being too critical on you by taking the issue further, sorry. It's not intended that way.

Comment: hi @roganjosh no problem . I understood what you meant and updated the answer now. constructive criticism is always welcome

Answer (score 1):

The file `write` method only expects strings (or bytestrings, if the file is open in binary mode). The `max` function can save you a conditional, too. Try something like:

```
with open('high_scores.py', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(str(max(player1_total, player2_total)))
```

You would then be able to read this back with

```
with open('high_scores.py') as f:
    high_score = int(f.read())
```

Note that the use of the `with` statements ensures that files are always correctly closed no matter what the outcome of the `with` block.

Personally, since the file isn't a Python program file I'd use a different extension in its name. For storing a larger set of values consider using the `shelve` module.

Answer (score 0):

cast your values to strings before writing to file:
`myFile.write(str(player1_total))`